# Is there a method to check whether the current Map is in Map or Satellite mode?

Tags: android, dictionary, android-mapview, satellite

I am setting the Map to Satellite view on click of a toggle button

```
 mapToggle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
     {

         public void onClick(View v)
         {
             if (mapToggle.isChecked())
             {   
                 mapV.setSatellite(true);  

             } else {   
                 mapV.setSatellite(false);  
             }   
    }});
```

I want to programitically determine which mode it is in when the app restarts. Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I accomplished this is to set an int value in your SharedPreferences.  Then onClick of that button, get the value and switch satellite on or off accordingly.

```
private static final int OVERLAY_STREET = 0;
private static final int OVERLAY_SAT = 1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    int currentOverlayMode = prefs.getInt("map_viewmode", 0);

    mOverlayModeBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.googlemaps_overlay_btn);
    mOverlayModeBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (currentOverlayMode < 1)
                currentOverlayMode++;
            else
                currentOverlayMode = 0;
            switch (currentOverlayMode) {
            case OVERLAY_STREET:
                mMaps.setSatellite(false);
                mMaps.setStreetView(true);
                prefsEditor.putInt("map_viewmode", OVERLAY_STREET);
                break;
            case OVERLAY_SAT:
                mMaps.setStreetView(false);
                mMaps.setSatellite(true);
                prefsEditor.putInt("map_viewmode", OVERLAY_SAT);
                break;
            }
            prefsEditor.commit();
            mMaps.invalidate();
        }
    });
}
```

You may want to clean it up a little, but it works for me.